# Error: scrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or onScrollToIndexFailed React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

Estoy haciendo un carrusel o un slider con auto Scroll de imágenes en React native, funciona perfectamente , pero cuando inicia de nuevo a deslizar las imágenes, que en este caso son 3 me salta ese error. Incluso cuando intento deslizar manualmente las imágenes se regresa a la anterior imagen, en vez de avanzar a la siguiente. Hay alguna posibilidad de que sea mas optimo el proceso de auto scrolling para que no gaste tantos recursos?.

Código:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Image
} from 'react-native'

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const height = width * 0.2844;

export default function Carosuel2(props) {
    const[sliderIndex, setSliderIndex] = useState(0)
    const[maxSlider, setMaxSlider] = useState(2),

    setRef = (c) => {
        listRef = c;
    }

    scrollToIndex = (index, animated) => {
        listRef && listRef.scrollToIndex({ index, animated })
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        setInterval(function(){
            
            let nextIndex =0;
            if(sliderIndex < maxSlider ){
                nextIndex = sliderIndex + 1
            }
            scrollToIndex(nextIndex, true)
            setSliderIndex(nextIndex)
        },4000)
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <FlatList
                    
                    ref={setRef}
                    data={props.images}
                    horizontal
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    pagingEnabled
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({item, i}) => (
                        <View key={i} style={{ height, width}}>
                            <Image style={{ height, width }} source={item.img} />
                        </View>
                    )}
                    onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => {
                        let sliderIndex = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x ? event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/width : 0
                        setSliderIndex(sliderIndex)
                    }}
                />
                <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
                    {
                        props.images.map(function(item, index) {
                            return (
                            <View key={index} style={styles.sliderBtnContainer}>
                                <View style={styles.sliderBtn}>
                                {
                                    sliderIndex == index ? <View style={styles.sliderBtnSelected}/> : null
                                }
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  sliderContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 80,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  sliderBtn: {
    height: 13,
    width: 13,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginRight: 10
  },
  sliderBtnSelected: {
    height: 12,
    width: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  sliderBtnContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 24
  },
});
```

El código lo saque del siguiente enlace: https://snack.expo.io/rJ9DOn0Ef , lo modifique para que pudiera funcionar con el useEffect, es decir intente actualizar las funciones.

Comment: Has intentado agregar `initialScrollIndex` a `FlatList`?

Comment: @milmal si, pero aun sigue dando el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos cosas porque tu código no corre.

- La primera cosa que yo veo es que no usas `useRef` para iniciar el ref.
- El otro problema es que no limpias tu intervalo. Necesitas usar `clearInterval`.

Aquí tienes un carrusel que funciona:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
} from "react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const height = width * 0.2844;
const images = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    imageUrl:
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_1280.jpg",
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    imageUrl:
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/16/05/forest-931706_1280.jpg",
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    imageUrl:
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/04/20/59/milky-way-1023340_1280.jpg",
  },
];

const Carosuel = () => {
  const [sliderIndex, setSliderIndex] = useState(0);
  const listRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToIndex = (index, animated) => {
    if (listRef) {
      listRef.current && listRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index, animated });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      let nextIndex = 0;
      if (sliderIndex < images.length - 1) {
        nextIndex = sliderIndex + 1;
      }
      scrollToIndex(nextIndex, true);
      setSliderIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{ height: 80, backgroundColor: "#123866", width: "100%" }}
      ></View>

      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollContainer}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <FlatList
          ref={listRef}
          data={images}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          pagingEnabled
          keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item, i }) => (
            <View key={i} style={{ height, width }}>
              <Image
                style={{ height, width }}
                source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }}
              />
            </View>
          )}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => {
            let newSliderIndex = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
              ? event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / width
              : 0;
            setSliderIndex(newSliderIndex);
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
          {images.map(function (item, index) {
            return (
              <View key={index} style={styles.sliderBtnContainer}>
                <View style={styles.sliderBtn}>
                  {sliderIndex == index ? (
                    <View style={styles.sliderBtnSelected} />
                  ) : null}
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sliderContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 80,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  sliderBtn: {
    height: 13,
    width: 13,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  sliderBtnSelected: {
    height: 12,
    width: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  sliderBtnContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 24,
  },
});

export default Carosuel;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :)